# Illumos kernel preprocessor macro

Tags: smartos

I can't find any info on what macro to use in an ifdef to determine the illumos kernel. I use __linux to catch Linux.

Filler for stackoverflow grammar check filler filler filler filler.

Answer (score 3):

Illumos based kernels such as SmartOS and OpenIndiana use `__sun` and it is [sometimes suggested](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/01/c_c_tip_how_use_compiler_predefined_macros_detect_operating_system#Solaris) to check for both `__sun` and `__SVR4`.

```
[root@mysmartostestzone ~]# uname -a
SunOS mysmartostestzone 5.11 joyent_20170202T033902Z i86pc i386 i86pc Solaris

[root@mysmartostestzone ~]# cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
#ifdef sun
printf("sun\n");
#endif

#ifdef __sun
printf("__sun\n");
#endif

#if defined(__sun) && defined(__SVR4)
printf("__sun && __SVR4\n");
#endif
}

[root@mysmartostestzone ~]# cc test.c

[root@mysmartostestzone ~]# ./a.out
sun
__sun
__sun && __SVR4
```

**Update:**

There will soon be an `__illumos__` macro:
https://www.illumos.org/issues/13726

Comment: Dead link, but the code seems to work fine (my limited testing).